# pyinstaller fails building an exe - cannot find python39.lib/_bootlocale.pyc

Tags: pyinstaller, exe

I am using pyinstaller to create an exe.
This fails to build an exe with the following details.
This has previously worked ok and I do have a copy of a working control.exe.

command line is
pyinstaller --onefile  control.py --windowed --name control.exe

Any ideas?

#summary

```
5282 INFO: distutils: retargeting to non-venv dir 'C:\Python39\python39.zip'
20337 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook urllib3.packages.six.moves from 'C:\Python39\lib\
site-packages\\PyInstaller\hooks\pre_safe_import_module\hook-urllib3.packages.six.moves.py'.
29683 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook six.moves from 'C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\
PyInstaller\hooks\pre_safe_import_module\hook-six.moves.py'.
48020 INFO: Caching module dependency graph...
48263 ERROR: base_library.zip could not be created!
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
File "runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "C:\Python39\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 126, in run
run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 65, in run_build
PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 815, in main
build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 762, in build
exec(code, spec_namespace)
File "C:\Users\steve.beaumont\Work\Tools\U1000 ModbusTestApp\branches\U1000_ModbusApp_Enhanced_Dev\U1000_ModbusEnhanced.exe.spec", line 7, in <module>
a = Analysis(['ModbusTestApp_Control.py'],
File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 294, in __init__
self.__postinit__()
File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 159, in __postinit__
self.assemble()
File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 403, in assemble
create_py3_base_library(libzip_filename, graph=self.graph)
File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\utils.py", line 81, in create_py3_base_library
st = os.stat(mod.filename)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\Python39\ython39.zip\\_bootlocale.pyc'
```

#summary

I am expecting pyinstaller to rebuild an exe.
There are no issues with file/directory permissions.
The file
'C:\Python39\python39.zip\_bootlocale.pyc'
exists in this .zip and directory
directory is in the path.

Comment: I can get the same problem trying to compile this file:
'''
__author__ = 'company.ltd'
__maintained__ = 'user 1'
__version__ = "v01.01.01"
"""
Test program
"""
import sys
import os

def main()
 print(sys.version)

if __name__ == '__main__':
 main()
'''

Comment: This was solved by expanding c:\python39\python39.zip to a dir called "python39.zip".

Comment: see https://blog.csdn.net/lefend/article/details/123084707 - there is 1 line of english in there which describes hte solution.